# In C, what are ways to make a function share data between its invocations?

Tags: c, function, loops, static

I am coding an application in C. One of the screens has a cursor. The cursor needs to keep blinking. I have a infinite while loop that keeps refreshing the screen. To get the effect of blinking, at every fifth iteration of this `while` loop, the cursor needs to alternate between appear and disappear.

I need to somehow keep a count of the iteration. I can declare a variable outside the `while` loop that can do the counting, but feel that this is inelegant because I have a `drawCursor()` function that updates the state of the cursor and this needs to take care of it without me having to declare this variable outside the `while` loop.

Is there a way to do it without having this count integer? What is an elegant way to accomplish this cursor blinking effect?

Comment: The most elegant way to accomplish a blinking cursor is to leave the blinking to the terminal, e.g. via ncurses...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply have a `static` variable inside the function.

```
void drawCursor()
{
    static int counter;

    if ((counter++ % 5) == 0)
    {
        // toggle the cursor state 
    }

}
```

Comment: Neat! Just curious.. where is memory allocated for counter? Is it where the program itself is stored?

Comment: It's normally in the static/global part of the program's memory, along with all other global variables, so yes. It's stored in the same way as any other global variable, except that it's only visible from inside the `drawCursor()` function.

Comment: also, when do you initialize counter? If you don't initialize it, how do you make sure it starts from 0?

Comment: @user1210233 All static variables are guaranteed to be initialized to zero, by the standard. However, it might not matter in this case: even if counter contains garbage, it will only trigger the toggle once every 5 iterations, which is what we're interested in, we don't care of the actual counter value. And that's why you don't need to check for an overflow of the counter either.

Comment: Well, overflow of an `int` is UB so you could argue for checking that (or using an unsigned type) if you think it will go on that long. I doubt that this particular code would actually suffer: I can't think of any likely optimizations that would prevent it wrapping around, which is what typical implementations do on overflow most of the time. Signed wraparound would likely cause one blink to be the wrong length, since 7 + 1 isn't -8 (mod 5), likewise unsigned since 5 + 1 isn't 0 (mod 5).